# TLSv1.2 on Azure PostgreSQL Server

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to ensure that the PostgreSQL client's connection to Azure PostgreSQL server (version 10.7) is using TLSv1.2.  When I execute `psql` command, the connection header shows me protocol `TLSv1.2`:

```
[user ~]# psql -h psql_server.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U psql_admin_accnt@psql_server -W postgres
Password:
psql (10.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

Yet, when I query `pg_stat_ssl` table, I get information, that the current connection is using `TLSv1.1` and `cipher` information isn't the same either.

```
postgres=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_ssl;
  pid   | ssl | version |        cipher        | bits | compression | clientdn
--------+-----+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+----------
 168648 | t   | TLSv1.1 | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA |  256 | f           |
(1 row)
```

Which information is the correct one and I should rely on?  Does my `psql` connection really uses `TLSv1.2` or it is `TLSv1.1` as seen from PostgreSQL system tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue was fixed by Microsoft itself

```
[user@host ~]$ /usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql "host=psql_server.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=dbname user=psql_admin_accnt@psql_server sslmode=require sslrootcert=/path/to/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.cer"
Password:
psql (10.11)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

dbname=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_ssl WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();
  pid   | ssl | version |           cipher            | bits | compression | clientdn
--------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+----------
 812820 | t   | TLSv1.2 | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 |  256 | f           |
(1 row)

dbname=> SELECT VERSION();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 10.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Now, the TLS version is correctly returned.